# Get value from deserialised JSON

Tags: json, map, string, deserialize

I have a JSON string which looks like this:

```
jsonstring = {"XX":["Blah blah"]}
```

I need to get the 'Blah blah' into a string variable. How do I do this?

Tried doing it this way, but all that returned was '{', so that's not working.

```
string result = (String)JSON.deserialize(jsonstring, String.Class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [JSON.deserializeUntyped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) to get an Object and you can typecast it further into a Map .

You can then easily start reading the object with key and typecasting it further.

```
String jsonstring = '{"XX":["Blah blah"]}';

Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonstring);

System.debug((List<Object>)m.get('XX'));

for(Object o : (List<Object>)m.get('XX')) {
   system.debug((String) o);
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but then I get this error:  Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to String. Why would that be?

Comment: I just fixed it . Sounds like it is array of string and hence you need an array . Check it out .